# What's the markup for a right arrow with an f over it (example image included)?

Tags: support, mathjax

How do I mark-up an arrow with an f over it?

[image]

Comment: This question is better suited for TeX.SE, not Meta.Math.SE

Comment: @anorton MathJax questions are off-topic at TeX.

Comment: @Rafflesiaarnoldii As much as I usually agree with you, the syntax for $X\overset f \to Y$ is *exactly* the same in TeX as it is with MathJax.  Asking "how do I mark-up an arrow with an f over it" on the TeX site would, if it didn't get closed for not containing a minimal-compilable example/lack of work, provide the answer the OP sought.  Even so, Meta.Math.SE is not MathJax.SE; at the very least, this question isn't on-topic here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about `$X\overset{f}\to Y$`: $X\overset{f}\to Y$?

Of course, you may choose some other type of arrow; see [here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/LaTeX:Symbols#Arrows) or [here](http://www.sascha-frank.com/Arrow/latex-arrows.html) (or [elsewhere](http://www.google.com/search?q=latex+arrows)).

Comment: When the content is long this isn't really good looking: $\overset{f \circ g \circ h}\to$.

Answer (score 19):

`$X \xrightarrow{f} Y$` gives $X \xrightarrow{f} Y$. It stretches according to the length of what's inside, for example $\xrightarrow{abcdefgh}$).

You can also put something under the arrow if you want, like that: `X \xrightarrow[a]{b} Y` gives $X \xrightarrow[a]{b} Y$.

Comment: This is strictly the *right* way to do this.

Comment: +1 I am glad that I have learned something new. We will see whether the OP will change the accepted answer. If not, at least there is (at least theoretical) chance of [populist badge](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/39/populist) for you.

Comment: +1 Just so you get that +10 for the badge ;) Also, very nice answer!